# MySQL performance on large, write-only table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, amazon-aurora

thanks in advance for your answers, and sorry for my bad english, I'm not a native speaker.

We're actually developping a mobile game with a backend. In this mobile game, we've got a money system, we keep track of each transaction for verification purpose.

In order to read a user balance, we've got an intermediary table, in which the user balance is updated on each transaction so the transaction table is never read directly by the users, in order to reduce load on high traffics.

The transaction table is uniquely read from time to time in the backoffice.

Here is the schema of the transaction table :

```
create table money_money_transaction (
  `id`              BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `userID`          INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `amount`          INT NOT NULL,
  `transactionType` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `created`         DATETIME NOT NULL,

  CONSTRAINT money_money_transaction_userID FOREIGN KEY (`userID`) REFERENCES `user_user` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

We planned to have a lot of users, the transaction table could grow up to 1 billion row, so my questions are :

- Will it affect the performance of other tables ?
- If the database is too large to fit in RAM, does MySQL have some sort of optimisation, storing in RAM only the most read table ?
- Does MySQL will be able to scale correctly up to this billion row ? Knowing we do mostly insert and that the only index is on the id (the id is needed for details) and that there is no "bulk insert" (there will not be 1M insert to do concurrently on this table)
- Also, we're on a RDS server, so we could switch to Aurora and try a master-master or master-slave replication if needed. Do you think it would help in this case ?

Comment: Basically this is a logging table?  Do you ever read from in in Business-As-Usual situations?  As such, does it really need the Foreign Key constraint?  Why is it important to fit in to RAM *(It will only be cached to RAM if it is frequently READ from.)*  Whether MySQL will scale well depends on how you use it, without much more information we can only say "It can, yes, but ***you*** can mean that it doesn't..."  Without knowing exactly how you will utilise this table *(You've only really described how you Won't use it)*, it's impossible to know if alternatives would suit you better.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.

Actually, it's kind of a logging table, we read it only if a user account have suspicious activities. 
The foreign key constraint is needed for this query and data integrity (a user can be deleted if he ask us to).
I maybe expressed myself badly, but the aim of my question was more "Does MySQL will store more important tables in RAM", so it seems to be good according to your answer.

Comment: You might "want" the foreign key, but if you're concerned about the volume of writing to this table, you don't "need" the foreign key.  Analysis following suspicious activity isn't BAU, and you'll know the user exists if you're investigating a user.  If you delete a user then the orphaned records can be purged in a nightly or weekly batch process.  Etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Thaht make sense, If we have performances issues, that will be the first thing we will drop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider MyRocks (see http://myrocks.io), which is a third-party storage engine that is designed for fast INSERT speed and compressed data storage. I won't make a recommendation that you should switch to MyRocks, because I don't have enough information to make an unequivocal statement about it for your workload. But I will recommend that it's worth your time to evaluate it and see if it works better for your application.

> If the database is too large to fit in RAM, does MySQL have some sort of optimisation, storing in RAM only the most read table ?

Yes, MySQL (assuming InnoDB storage engine) stores partial tables in RAM, in the buffer pool. It breaks down tables into pages, and fits pages in the buffer pool as queries request them. It's like a cache. Over time, the most requested pages stay in the buffer pool, and others get evicted. So it more or less balances out to serve most of your queries as quickly as possible. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html for more information.

> Will it affect the performance of other tables ?

Tables don't have performance — *queries* have performance.

The buffer pool has fixed size. Suppose you have six tables that need to share it, their pages must fit into the same buffer pool. There's no way to set priorities for each table, or dedicate buffer pool space for certain tables or "lock" them in RAM. All pages of all tables share the same buffer pool. So as your queries request pages from various tables, they do affect each other in the sense that frequently-requested pages from one table may evict pages from another table.

> Does MySQL will be able to scale correctly up to this billion row ?

MySQL has many features to try to help performance and scalability (those are not the same thing). Again, queries have performance, not tables. A table without queries just sits there. It's the queries that get optimized by different techniques.

> Knowing we do mostly insert and that the only index is on the id (the id is needed for details) and that there is no "bulk insert" (there will not be 1M insert to do concurrently on this table)

Indexes do add overhead to inserts. You can't eliminate the primary key index, this is a necessary part of every table. But for example, you might find it worthwhile to drop your FOREIGN KEY, which includes an index.

Usually, most tables are read more than they are written to, so it's worth keeping an index to help reads (or even an UPDATE or DELETE that uses a WHERE clause). But if your workload is practically all INSERT, maybe the extra index for the foreign key is purely overhead and gives no benefit for any queries.

> Also, we're on a RDS server, so we could switch to Aurora and try a master-master or master-slave replication if needed. Do you think it would help in this case ?

I worked on benchmarks of Aurora in early 2017, and found that for the application we tested, is was not good for high write traffic. You should always test it for your application, instead of depending on the guess of someone on the internet. But I predict that Aurora in its current form (circa 2017) will completely suck for your all-write workload.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! really complete.

I think MyRocks isn't for my use case (the rest of the database is mostly read) but it's something definitively worth checking.

Comment: Note that MySQL allows you to choose the storage engine per table. Choosing MyRocks for one table does not require you to use MyRocks for all your tables.

Comment: Isn't there a risk for transactionnal integrity if it's not the same engine when you make a transaction inserting on different tables ?

Comment: Yes, I must retract my comment above. It's "experimental" according to https://github.com/facebook/mysql-5.6/wiki/Getting-Started-with-MyRocks and risky to mix InnoDB with MyRocks, because MySQL does not support transactions that include changes to multiple storage engines.

Comment: If I can ask you one more question :
If this table reach 2 billions row, that I never read from it and that the only queries I make on it are simple inserts, one at a time (let's say, ten single inserts per second). Do you think performances will suffer ?

Comment: @Argurth, performance of what, of the inserts? The inserts might become slightly slower as the table gets larger, but I doubt it will be noticeable. Here's a benchmark comparison of InnoDB vs. MyRocks for insert: http://smalldatum.blogspot.com/2017/01/insert-benchmark-myrocks-and-innodb.html

Comment: Yes, I was talking about insert, thank you for the quick answer !